# Как сделать круговую диаграмму на SVG с заливкой?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать вот такую круговую диаграмму, с заливкой в центре заполненной части.

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 164 164" style=""
     class="">
    <g>
        <path transform="rotate(90 82 82)" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4" d="M2,82A80,80 0,1,1 162,82A80,80 0,1,1 2,82" class="start"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Как сделать заливку?**

Бордер генерирую [вот так](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NEzEpP):

```js
var stroke = 477, bg = 251;
  var percent = $('svg').attr('data-percent'),
      newStroke = stroke * (percent/100),
      newbg = bg * (percent/100);
      $('.start-2').css('stroke-dasharray', newBg+' '+bg);
      $('.start').css('stroke-dasharray', newStroke+' '+stroke);
  console.log(newStroke+' '+stroke);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.start {
  stroke-dasharray: 238.5 477;
  transition: 1s;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  fill:none;
  stroke:green;
  stroke-width:4;
}
.start-2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 125.5 251;
  transition: 1s;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 75;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<svg data-role="pie-chart" data-percent="60" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 164 164" style="enable-background:new 0 0 164 164;" xml:space="preserve">
  <radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="82" cy="82" r="78.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
 <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
 <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#e4e4e4; stop-opactity: .5"/>
</radialGradient>
<circle transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" class="start-2" style="stroke:url(#SVGID_1_)"  cx="82" cy="82" r="40"/>
<circle transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" class="start" cx="82" cy="82" r="76"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил самостоятельно. Может кому пригодится.

```js
var stroke = 477,
  bg = 251;

$('[data-role="pie-chart"]').each(function() {
  var percent = $(this).attr('data-percent'),
    newStroke = stroke * (percent / 100),
    newBg = bg * (percent / 100),
    $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.pie-chart__bg', $this).css('stroke-dasharray', newBg + ' ' + bg);
    $('.pie-chart__border', $this).css('stroke-dasharray', newStroke + ' ' + stroke);
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.pie-chart {
  width: 300px;
}

.pie-chart__gradient-from {
  stop-color: #fff;
  stop-opacity: 1;
}

.pie-chart__gradient-to {
  stop-color: #e2e2e2;
  stop-opacity: .75;
}

.pie-chart__bg {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 251;
  transition: 1s;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 75;
}

.pie-chart__border {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 477;
  transition: 1s;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #757575;
  stroke-width: 4;
}

.pie-chart_gray .pie-chart__border {
  stroke: #757575;
}

.pie-chart_yellow .pie-chart__border {
  stroke: #F9DF3C;
}

.pie-chart_orange .pie-chart__border {
  stroke: #FC9C1E;
}

.pie-chart_green .pie-chart__border {
  stroke: #86BF40;
}

.pie-chart_blue .pie-chart__border {
  stroke: #214DA6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="pie-chart pie-chart_green" data-role="pie-chart" data-percent="50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 164 164" style="enable-background:new 0 0 164 164;"
  xml:space="preserve">
  <radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="82" cy="82" r="78.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-from" offset="0"></stop>
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-to" offset="1"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <circle class="pie-chart__bg" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" style="stroke:url(#SVGID_1_);" cx="82" cy="82" r="40"></circle>
  <circle class="pie-chart__border" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" cx="82" cy="82" r="76"></circle>
  <text x="82" y="94" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeueCyr', sans-serif; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 500; fill: #4a4a4a;">50%</text>
</svg>
<svg class="pie-chart pie-chart_orange" data-role="pie-chart" data-percent="87" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 164 164" style="enable-background:new 0 0 164 164;"
  xml:space="preserve">
  <radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="82" cy="82" r="78.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-from" offset="0"></stop>
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-to" offset="1"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <circle class="pie-chart__bg" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" style="stroke:url(#SVGID_1_);" cx="82" cy="82" r="40"></circle>
  <circle class="pie-chart__border" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" cx="82" cy="82" r="76"></circle>
  <text x="82" y="94" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeueCyr', sans-serif; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 500; fill: #4a4a4a;">87%</text>
</svg>
<svg class="pie-chart pie-chart_blue" data-role="pie-chart" data-percent="15" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 164 164" style="enable-background:new 0 0 164 164;"
  xml:space="preserve">
  <radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="82" cy="82" r="78.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-from" offset="0"></stop>
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-to" offset="1"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <circle class="pie-chart__bg" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" style="stroke:url(#SVGID_1_);" cx="82" cy="82" r="40"></circle>
  <circle class="pie-chart__border" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" cx="82" cy="82" r="76"></circle>
  <text x="82" y="94" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeueCyr', sans-serif; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 500; fill: #4a4a4a;">15%</text>
</svg>
<svg class="pie-chart pie-chart_gray" data-role="pie-chart" data-percent="44" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 164 164" style="enable-background:new 0 0 164 164;"
  xml:space="preserve">
  <radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="82" cy="82" r="78.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-from" offset="0"></stop>
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-to" offset="1"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <circle class="pie-chart__bg" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" style="stroke:url(#SVGID_1_);" cx="82" cy="82" r="40"></circle>
  <circle class="pie-chart__border" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" cx="82" cy="82" r="76"></circle>
  <text x="82" y="94" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeueCyr', sans-serif; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 500; fill: #4a4a4a;">44%</text>
</svg>
<svg class="pie-chart pie-chart_yellow" data-role="pie-chart" data-percent="60" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 164 164" style="enable-background:new 0 0 164 164;"
  xml:space="preserve">
  <radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="82" cy="82" r="78.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-from" offset="0"></stop>
    <stop class="pie-chart__gradient-to" offset="1"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <circle class="pie-chart__bg" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" style="stroke:url(#SVGID_1_);" cx="82" cy="82" r="40"></circle>
  <circle class="pie-chart__border" transform="rotate(-90 82 82)" cx="82" cy="82" r="76"></circle>
  <text x="82" y="94" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeueCyr', sans-serif; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 500; fill: #4a4a4a;">60%</text>
</svg>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BGPoGN)

Comment: Как по мне лучше уж canvas:)

Comment: На сколько я знаю, на канвасе не очень обстоят дела с анимацией.

Comment: Очень интересно, где вы об этом услышали?=)

Comment: Нигде не слышал, я сделал вывод основываясь на своих знаниях)

Comment: Сможете показать пример с аналогичным результатом на канвасе?
Анимация, градиент, а так же чтобы можно было по клику сменить % в диаграмме и анимация пошла с того места, где она находилась на момент нажатия, а не с нуля

P.S. Подключать сторонние библиотеки нельзя :)